# How to upload a pdf to "cloudinary" using jquery and retrieve the link to that pdf?

Tags: java, jquery, cloudinary

I have generated a PDF from `itextpdf`, now I want to upload this PDF file to "cloudinary" and save the link of uploaded portable document file in database. I can use both jquery and java for this purpose. I think that "cloudinary" returns json data and link can be taken from this json data?

Comment: Have you looked at this?: http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#uploading_with_a_direct_call_to_the_api

Comment: this documentary is for uploading image

Comment: pdf files can be uploaded to Cloudinary as images.

Answer (score 0):

Using Cloudinary's Java library, something like this should be what you're looking for:

```
import com.cloudinary.Cloudinary;

Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary();
Map response = cloudinary.upload("my_file.pdf", ObjectUtils.asMap("resource_type", "raw"));
String url = (String) response.get("url");
// Add url to database
```

[Regarding configuration parameters for secure API calls](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/java_integration#configuration)

Doing it manually is more involved (sans Cloudinary's libary), but I can take you through it if you'd like.

Comment: In case of pdf files, no need to set the resource_type to raw. They are accepted as images as well.